# Where is the small row width defined in Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation

While I see the `$row-width: emCalc(1000px);` in _variables.css, I can't find where the small width is defined for mobile devices. I'm assuming it's just set to 100% but I'd like to play around with changing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct : **The row-width variable just sets the maximum width**.
The width of the `.row` is always 100%

- When it's a large screen, the width is constrained by the max-width variable, so it's by default 1000px
- When it's a small screen (as a mobile device), the `.row` width is 100%.

> I'm assuming it's just set to 100% but I'd like to play around with
>   changing this.

You may consider to change the breakpoint width, or using different structure (columns?).